# Show the most recently added row in a table for each distinct name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say this is my table schema

```
Create Table PowerReading
{ Device VARCHAR(32);
  Power INT;
  Time TIMESTAMP;
}
```

Say these are the rows in my table

```
Device | Power | Time
A3     |   5   | 2013-05-01 17:36:00
A3     |   9   | 2013-05-01 17:37:44
B1     |  11   | 2013-05-01 17:35:14
B1     |   5   | 2013-05-01 17:35:55
B7     |   4   | 2013-05-01 17:34:12
B7     |   0   | 2013-05-01 17:34:44
```

I've spent like days trying to figure out how to show the reading that is the most recent for each DISTINCT device name. I want an SQL query that gives THIS output from the above table.

```
 Device | Power | Time
A3     |   9   | 2013-05-01 17:37:44
B1     |   5   | 2013-05-01 17:35:55
B7     |   0   | 2013-05-01 17:34:44
```

I've tried to accomplish using the below code, but it's useless

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Device,Power,MAX(Time) as Max FROM PowerReading GROUP
BY Device,Power) t1 JOIN PowerReading on t1.Device=PowerReading.Device AND      
t1.max=PowerReading.Power
```

What the above code gives me is an output that is not to my desired output
This little issue has been eating my head for days. Please help me? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived table was using a `group by` on `power` column as well, which is not needed.

```
SELECT p.* FROM 
(SELECT Device, MAX(Time) as maxtime 
 FROM PowerReading
 GROUP BY Device) t1 
JOIN PowerReading p on t1.Device = p.Device AND t1.maxtime = p.time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively do it using variables:

```
SELECT Device, Power, Time
FROM (
  SELECT Device, Power, Time,
         @rn := IF (@dev = Device, @rn + 1,
                    IF(@dev := Device, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM PowerReading
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @dev := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY Device, Time DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Variable `@rn` essentially simulates `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Device ORDER BY Time DESC` window function, available in other RDBMSs.

The above query will select *exactly one* row per `Device` even if there are more than one rows sharing the exact same timestamp.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f7af/2)

Comment: I'll understand this concept. It did go a little over my head but I guess that's because I am probably a novice/newb/dumb. In spite of that you were able to introduce me to the the concept of using variables in SQL query. Thank you so much for your time :-)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select pr.*
from PowerReading pr
where pr.time = (select max(time) from PowerReading pr2 where pr2.dev = pr.dev);
```

This version can make optimal use of an index on `PowerReading(dev, time)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a more cleaner looking SQL query :D